# Apache not loading php.ini

Tags: php, apache

Currently I've got my PHP7.0.0RC5 compiled in a CentOS7.1.1503 box. However when I try to print phpinfo(), the list told me that the `Loaded Configuration File` was `(none)`.

Some facts are listed below:

1. there is no other PHP version installed in this box;
2. configuration parameter `--with-config-file-path=/home/myusername/php7/etc` is set;
3. `--with-config-file-scan-dir` is not set;
4. in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, I've added:

   ```
   LoadModule php7_module        /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
5. I've copied the `php.ini-development` to that folder and renamed it to `php.ini`;
6. the owner and group of the file is root, authentication is 644, the path to the file are all set to 755;
7. the command `/home/myusername/php7/bin/php --ini` could find the `php.ini` file in the right place.

So did I miss something here?

**EDIT.0**

I've recompiled PHP7 with prefix `/opt/php7` and without `--with-config-file-path` parameter. Now it works fine, but what is the problem with the parameter `--prefix=/home/myusername/php7` and `--with-config-file-path=/home/myusername/php7/etc`?

**EDIT.1**

Recompiled PHP7 with prefix `/home/myusername/php7` and without `--with-config-file-path` parameter. Still doesn't work.

**EDIT.2**

After several tries, I've set `--prefix=/home/myusername/php7` and `--with-config-file-path=/etc/local/lib` for configure. And then everything works well. It seems that for Apache, the `php.ini` shouldn't be located in a user's home folder. But the reason still remains unknown.

Comment: try entering a " which php " command and comment in what it prints out

Comment: @soden Hi, thx for the reply. I've run PHP with absolute path, so I'm pretty sure the `php --ini` shows the right information. And the phpinfo call also shows the version number 7.0.0RC5.

Comment: Is this file exist? `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

Comment: @ji-ruh Yes, it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add this command to your `httpd.conf` file?

```
PHPIniDir "(php.ini path)"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add more context to your answer if possible. A brief explanation about how your solution might resolve the issue can be of great value for the topic owner or anybody else having the same question.